# Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool - Connections stuck on active

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, connection-pooling

My application uses Tomcat JDBC connection pool, with MySQL DB.
Seems like a process that run during the night (anti virus scan?) cause the memory and CPU on the machine to increase, and as a result connections from the pool stuck on active until the connection pool can't response to any connection request.

I'm getting errors like:

- `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after statement closed`.
- `Timeout: Pool empty. Unable to fetch a connection in 10 seconds, none available[size:100; busy:97; idle:0; lastwait:10000]. (That's weird, where are the remaining 3?)`

Looking at a chart I'm generating describing the active connection state, it is flat until at some point it start increasing until it reach the maximum and stays there.
My connection pool is configure to remove unclosed connections (`setRemoveAbandoned = true`).

Do you have any idea how can I solve this issue?

Comment: What is the application for? You could set a timeout for connections on mysql and tomcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because your application not closing connections after use. Please check your code and make sure all connections are closing after use.